# What roles are needed to download an object from a Google Storage Bucket

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-python, google-cloud-iam

I have created a service account and given it only the `Storage Object Viewer` role. I would like to use this service account to download objects from a bucket using the python API.

I have set the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable accordingly and can see the relevant service account showing up on the bucket's permissions page.

I use the following code to try and download an object

```py
from google.cloud import storage
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(BUCKET_NAME)
```

But I get the following error when calling `get_bucket`

```
google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden: 
403 GET https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/samplereadbucket?projection=noAcl: 
sample-service-account@project.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.buckets.get 
access to samplereadbucket.
```

What is the minimum set of roles I need to set so that the service account has `storage.buckets.get` access if not `Storage Object Viewer`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Storage Object Viewer (`roles/storage.objectViewer`) only includes these permissions:

```
resourcemanager.projects.get
resourcemanager.projects.list
storage.objects.get
storage.objects.list
```

For buckets, you will need a role like Storage Legacy Bucket Reader (`roles/storage.legacyBucketReader`) (or create a [custom role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles)).  This gives you:

```
storage.buckets.get
storage.objects.list
```

You can always use the [IAM & Admin > Roles](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/roles) tab in the cloud console to search for the specific permissions to see what roles currently grant those permissions.

Comment: I was thrown off by the word `Legacy` and thought I shouldn't be using those roles. This looks to be the correct answer though!

Comment: You can also just create a custom role.

Comment: Here's also a link to the Storage Role documentation for anyone in the future: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#storage-roles

Comment: I also thought I wouldn't/shouldn't need to create a custom role to do something as common as download an object from a bucket. =P

Comment: Sure, I suppose you also could use the Storage Admin role, but that seems wrong too :)

Comment: Yes, granting your service account the **Storage Admin** role would work as well.

Answer (score 0):

it's needed to add these roles to the SA:

```
Storage Object Viewer (roles/storage.objectViewer)

   resourcemanager.projects.get
   resourcemanager.projects.list
   storage.objects.get
   storage.objects.list

Storage Legacy Bucket Reader (roles/storage.legacyBucketReader)

   storage.buckets.get 
   storage.multipartUploads.list
   storage.objects.list
```

Or even better would be creating a custom role with roles